# How can I bring the product ID in Excel Sheet1 from Excel Sheet2 for each Product even if it is a duplicate?

Tags: excel, search, vlookup, lookup

I have data on two excel sheets as below.

Sheet1:

| Product Name | City | Other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | XY | 123 |
| A | XY | 1233 |
| B | TT | 6456 |
| B | TT | 787 |
| A | XY | 898 |
| C | XY | 898 |

Sheet2:

| Productid | Product Name | Other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 133 |
| 2 | B | 3331 |
| 3 | A | 4441 |
| 4 | C | 4441 |
| 5 | A | 8787 |
| 6 | A | 989 |

How can I bring the product ID in Excel Sheet1 from Excel Sheet2 for each Product even if it is a duplicate?
I am trying this way in Excel using VLOOKUP

=VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!A:C;0;FALSE)

but it giving me error #N/A, not even giving me the first match value.

My Expected Result:

| Productid | Product Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A | XY |
| 5 | A | XY |
| 1 | B | TT |
| 2 | B | TT |
| 6 | A | XY |
| 4 | C | XY |

Comment: Try using `MATCH` and `INDEX`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad any example?

Comment: With VLOOKUP the return column must be to the right of the lookup column. If your excel version has it try XLOOKUP  eg. `=XLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A,"No ID",0)`